# How to send mail in batch file using smtp without providing password

Tags: email, batch-file

I have a batch file which is in scheduler which always pings for a new build existence and if exists it starts automation on new build. I want to have a notification by adding send mail commands in batch file to know the scheduler batch file has picked the new builds.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) command line tool. It requires a quick setup to record the SMTP server, port, from address, etc. (or you can specify them in each call if you like), but once this is done you can use very terse commands.

For example:

```
SET EmailTo=my@email.com

REM Send an email notice that the setup has started along with a timestamp.
REM First parameter as a dash indicates we will provide the body text,
REM  otherwise we could specify a text file here and it will be the body.
Blat - -to %EmailTo% -subject "Setup Started" -body "Started on %DATE% - %TIME"

REM Do some stuff...

REM Send an email notice that the setup is complete along with a log file.
Blat "C:\Path\To\Log.txt" -to %EmailTo% -subject "Setup Complete"
```

Comment: when I issue blat standalone command in cmd prompt it says blat command not found appears. What could be the solution for this?

Comment: @Joshi - Did you download the tool and put it (and all the components included with it) in a folder in your PATH directory (e.g. C:\Windows)?